# We repeatedly toss a fair coin until we see ‘heads’. Let X be the number of tosses we need. Compute the probability that X is a multiple of 3.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm given the problem

> We repeatedly toss a fair coin until we see ‘heads’. Let X be the number of tosses we need. Compute the probability that X is a multiple of 3.

I did find a solution to this problem, shown below, that uses an infinite sum.

I was wondering if there was a solution where no knowledge of infinite sums is required.

---

This was my solution:
The probability that X is a multiple of 3 is equal to the probability that heads lands first on the 3rd throw + the probability that heads lands first on the 6th throw etc.
This is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{3n}}$. As this is a geometric series with ratio equal to 1/8 this sum is equal to (1/8)/(7/8) = 1/7.

Comment: Hints: what is the probability you get at least one heads in the first three tosses?  What is the probability that the first time you get heads is the third toss?

Comment: This is a copy of your homework. But what is your question?

Comment: I've edited your question to better emphasize the question you're asking. Also, I've formatted the sum you were writing; if you edit your post again you can see how to do the formatting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a solution where no knowledge of infinite sums is required.

There is actually a way to solve this pretending no infinite series is involved, but, IMHO, this is more hiding the series under the rug than really avoiding it.

Anyway, simply note that, if $3$ divides $X$, then:

- either $X=3$, when the three first results are tails, tails, heads, which happens with probability $\frac18$,
- or $X=3+X'$, when the three first results are tails, tails, tails, which happens with probability $\frac18$, and then $X'$ denotes the first time one sees heads in the sequence of tosses starting at the fourth toss, and one demands that $3$ divides $X'$.

Thus, $$P(3\text{ divides }X)=\frac18+\frac18P(3\text{ divides }X')$$ Furthermore, $$P(3\text{ divides }X')=P(3\text{ divides }X)$$ hence $$P(3\text{ divides }X)=\frac{\frac18}{1-\frac18}=\frac17$$